# how I can add a column with all 1 to my dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame and I want to add a new column with entries 1. how I can do that?

for example

```
   col1.  col2
    1.     2. 
    4.     5. 
    33.     4. 
    5.     3.
```

new column

```
   col1.  col2.  col3
    1.     2.     1
    4.     5.     1
    33.     4.    1
    5.     3.     1
```

Comment: Jusst do `cbind(df1, col3 = 1)` or `df1['col3'] <- 1`

Answer (score 3):

```
df1$col3 <- 1
```

this should work as well

likewise as above

```
df1<-data.frame(df1,col3=1)
```

could also work

Answer (score 0):

Simplest option is to do `?Extract`

```
df1['col3'] <- 1
```

One of the good things about using `[` instead of `$` is that we can pass variable identifiers as well

```
v1 <- 'col3'
df1[v1] <- 1
```

But, if we do

```
df1$v1 <- 1
```

it creates a column with name as 'v1' instead of 'col3'

---

Other variations without changing the initial object would be

```
transform(df1, col3 = 1)
cbind(df1, col3 = 1)
```

NOTE: All of these creates a column appended as the last column

---

Also, there is a convenient function `add_column` which can add a column by specifying the position.  By default, it creates the column as the last one

```
library(tibble)
add_column(df1, col3 = 1)
#  col1. col2 col3
#1     1    2    1
#2     4    5    1
#3    33    4    1
#4     5    3    1
```

But, if we need to change it to a specific location, there are arguments

```
add_column(df1, col3 = 1, .after = 1)
#   col1. col3 col2
#1     1    1    2
#2     4    1    5
#3    33    1    4
#4     5    1    3
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(col1. = c(1, 4, 33, 5), col2 = c(2, 5, 4, 3)),
    class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```